# Cannot navigate to view from mapview calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method

Tags: swiftui, navigation, mapview

When user taps on mapview annotation rightCalloutAccessoryView disclosure button, I want to navigate to another view

[image: AnnotationView]

```
 struct ProfileMapView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                MapView(locationPins: $locationPins)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    // some code
    class MapViewDelegate: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            //MARK:- delegate method
            func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
                if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView  {
                    mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)
                    
                    for detail in self.myAnnotations {
                        locationId = detail.locationId
                        providerType = detail.providerType
                        NavigationStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("test")
                                
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: ProfileDetailsView(locationId: $locationId, providerType: $providerType),
                                    isActive: $isNavigationActive
                                ) {
                                    EmptyView()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I run it does not navigate to ProfileDetailsView. Instead debugger window shows a message: "Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update."
Also on the NavigationLink line, I get a warning "Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused"
How to navigate to another view from calloutAccessoryControlTapped method?

Comment: for `NavigationLink` to work it needs  a `NavigationStack`.

Comment: A delegate method can trigger navigation with isPresented:Bool or some other variable but a NavigationLink only work in the body

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(item:destination:)

Comment: I defined it in the delegate method like this:   NavigationStack {
navigateTo = AnyView(ProfileDetailsView(locationId: $locationId, providerType: $providerType))
 isNavigationActive = true
NavigationLink(destination: AnyView(self.navigateTo), isActive: $isNavigationActive) { EmptyView() } }. Since calloutAccessoryControlTapped method is part of Delegate, I get error Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'. How can I define it in the body

Comment: @vrao please edit your question rather than putting code/detail in the comments.  It's hard to follow when like the above

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Edited the original posting.  The method is defined in class confirming to MKMapViewDelegate. I get error Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'. Should I move the navigation out of the MKMapViewDelegate class, if so how can I define it in the outer view that comprises the delegate class

Comment: The last time I made edits, did not save it. I reedited and saved it again.